# One Class Library that has Dataset that does updates.....Convert this to MultiThreading Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, datatable

I have below code which does Updates....

Now For example if i have 200 Records, since it is Single Threaded, it takes 4 hours.
Now to improve the Performance/ bring down the Execution time, I need to make this as MultiThreaded (No of Threads should be Configurable anywhere from 5 to 10).

Appreciate your responses.

```
public class EnableFeature
    {
        public const string strPendingStatus = "P";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnableFeature obj = new EnableFeature();
            obj.ProcessRequests();

        }

        public void ProcessRequests()
        {
            DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
            //Get all the matching Records that has Pending Status from Database 
            objDs = EnableFeatureDAO.SelectByStatus(strPendingStatus);
            if (objDs != null && objDs.Tables.Count > 0 && objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //This needs to Multi Threaded
                foreach (DataRow objDr in objDs.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    //Business Object/ Business Layer Call
                    EnableFeatureBO objEnableFeatureBO = new EnableFeatureBO();
                    try
                    {
                        //Do updates by calling webservice internally here which has Stored Proc
                        //It has it's connection details to take care of Updates
                        //Backend is Oracle
                        // Order in which these are going doesn't matter as they open up a separate connection for each thread 
                        objEnableFeatureBO.EnableDisableFeatureExecuteScripts(
                            objDr[EnableFeatureDAO.COL_CUSTID],
                            objDr[EnableFeatureDAO.COL_ISICLIENTID], 
                            objDr[EnableFeatureDAO.COL_CLIENTDBSCHEMA], 
                            objDr[EnableFeatureDAO.COL_CLIENTDBSERVER]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //log Exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks
Rita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your business logic is all thread safe, you can just use a parallel for loop to iterate the rows (also assuming the rows do not get added or changed by the business logic).

```
    public void ProcessRequests(int maxThreads = 5)
    {
        DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
        objDs = EnableFeatureDAO.SelectByStatus(strPendingStatus);
        if (objDs != null && objDs.Tables.Count > 0 && objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads };

            Parallel.For(0, objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count, options, (i) =>
            {
                DataRow objDr = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[i];

                //Business Object/ Business Layer Call
                EnableFeatureBO objEnableFeatureBO = new EnableFeatureBO();
                try
                {
                    //Do updates by calling webservice internally here which has Stored Proc
                    //It has it's connection details to take care of Updates
                    //Backend is Oracle
                    // Order in which these are going doesn't matter as they open up a separate connection for each thread 
                    objEnableFeatureBO.EnableDisableFeatureExecuteScripts(
                        objDr[EnableFeatureDAO.COL_CUSTID],
                        objDr[EnableFeatureDAO.COL_ISICLIENTID],
                        objDr[EnableFeatureDAO.COL_CLIENTDBSCHEMA],
                        objDr[EnableFeatureDAO.COL_CLIENTDBSERVER]);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //log Exception
                }
            });

        }
    }
```